# jquery blur() event on window leave

Tags: jquery

if I close window on ipad it works, fine but if i hit url pop-up does'nt appears. 
just want to understand blur event behavior for ipad and iphones

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() <= 1025) {

        if ($("body #progressbar li:nth-child(2)").hasClass('active') && $("body #progressbar li:nth-child(3)").hasClass('active'))  {
            $("#movemodal").show();

        }
        else {
            $("#movemodal").hide();

        }


    }

})
```

Comment: it's simple, on `blur()` event it's checking window width, on `ipad` it's width is less than `1025`, so pop-up shown but on browser window width `>1025` so pop-up not shown.

Comment: yeah but the thing is when i select a option from drop down list this pop up comes up (which i putted on blur event) while i am not leaving window i am still here and selecting option from drop down. So is it a browser behavior or what?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `blur()` works the same for all sort of devices. If you write following code:

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
    console.log('works');
});
```

You will see you get the result everywhere.

Here issue if the condition you are putting inside your `blur()` function.

Make sure that you are targetting the window width the right way as you need it in your application. That must be the point of distinction here.